# Show available product sizes or the sizes count in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, string, woocommerce, product

This is the code I use to show available sizes in shoppage/categoriespage. What I am tryin to do is when there are a lot of sizes available example: (XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL, 4XL) then I want to hide this string and show alternative text like (9 sizes availabel)
Any help would be appreciated.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'mycode_add_size_above_product_title', 20 );
function mycode_add_size_above_product_title() {
global $product;
$size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
if ( ! empty( $size ) ) {
    echo '<div style="font-size:10px">' . $size . '</div>';
}
```

I tried this but its showing the sting two times!

```
if (strlen($string) <=50) {
 echo $string;
} else {
echo substr($string, 0, 50) . '...';
}
```

BEFORE:
LEVI'S 
XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, 3XL, 4XL
$65.00

EXPECTED RESULT: (only when more then 5 sizes available) 
LEVI'S 
9 Sizes available
$65.00

Comment: Right, and what have your tried yourself?

Comment: One of your options for echo should be "(9 sizes availabel)." You're having it print the same no matter the if/else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The following will limit the sizes display to 5 and if more it will display the count of available sizes:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'mycode_add_size_above_product_title', 20 );
function mycode_add_size_above_product_title() {
    global $product;

    if( $sizes = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' ) ) {
        $count = count( explode(', ', $sizes) ); // The size count

        if ( $count > 5 ) {
            echo '<div style="font-size:10px">' . $count . ' ' . __("sizes available!") . '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div style="font-size:10px">' . $sizes . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Of course you can adjust the number of sizes to be displayed replacing **5** by any integer…

Comment: I was hoping this would do the trick but I am getting errors in this line  if ( count( $sizes ) > 5 ) {

Comment: Wow its just so amazing. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your test for the length inside of the echoing of the div.

```
if (!empty($size)) {
    echo '<div style="font-size:10px">';
    if (strlen($size ) <=50) {
        echo $size;
    } else {
        echo substr($size , 0, 50) . '...';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. almost okay but didn't replaced it just cut it. if I can't find a better option then this would be very helpful.

Comment: In your question where does `$string` come from?

Comment: attribute / size